# Making index entries into links not working

Tags: hyperref, indexing, imakeidx

The usual problem: making index entries clickable.
Can't find the solution to my particular situation, even though the issue has been mentioned quite a few times on this website.
I've made sure that `\usepackage{hyperref}` comes after `\usepackage{imakeidx}` ... and yet, I get nothing.

Any help would be much welcomed.
Thank you.

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,centered]{bookest}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newpxtext} % Font for document instead of obsolete Palatino
\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % For shading in tables
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{nicefrac} % to write fractions
\usepackage{attrib} % For source of quotations
\usepackage{lettrine} % For NewThought formatting
\usepackage{array} % To define width of columns in long table
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer spacing in columns
\usepackage{siunitx} % To write Celsius, etc.
\usepackage{enumitem} % To create item lists
\usepackage{caption} % To change way captions are labelled
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}

%%%%%TEST_ZONE%%%%%%

\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\indexsetup{othercode=\small}
\makeindex[columns=3,title=Super Big Index,intoc]
%\usepackage{showidx} %To print all index entries in right margin to proofread entries

\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks

%%%%%TEST_ZONE%%%%%%

\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{showframe}

%\usepackage{chngcntr} % For continuous numbering of tables
%\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

% To change the style of the caption numbering.
%\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}

% To format the paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{4em} % For indentations
\setlength{\parskip}{1em} % For space between paragrpahs

% Defining how Celsius and Fahrenheit appear
\def\degC{$^\circ\kern-0.06em\rm{C}$}
\def\degF{$^\circ\kern-0.06em\rm{F}$}

%Table of Content depth
\geometry{verbose}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}

%Hyperlinks for TOC
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}

% Change footnotes from numbers to symbols
\makeatletter
\def\@xfootnote[#1]{%
    \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{#1}%
    \@footnotemark\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

% To sign quotes properly
%\def\signed #1{{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em
%       \hbox{}\nobreak\hfil(#1)%
%       \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \endgraf}}
%
%\newsavebox\mybox
%\newenvironment{aquote}[1]
%{\savebox\mybox{#1}\begin{quote}}
%   {\signed{\usebox\mybox}\end{quote}}

\begin{document}

% FRONTMATTER STARTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\listoftables
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{plain} % To not have "List of Tables appear" at the top of the "Preface" page
\section*{Preface}
\blindtext
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{plain} % To not have "List of Tables appear" at the top of the "Preface" page
\section*{Introduction}
\blindtext
\clearpage

% MAINMATTER STARTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter{The Mighty Chapter}
\index{nskfs}
\index{Nsfsjkfns}
\index{Nagag}

\index{qlsjbfz}

\index{Tly{\"a}nu|textbf}

\index{Goy{\'e}l}

\index{Aejhgjlh@{\ae}jhgjlh}

\index{Ald@{\'A}ld}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that the `bookest` class loads `hyperref`, which of course it shouldn't. Leave it alone; by the way, a class that redefines `\MakeUppercase` should be banned.

Comment: `\rm` has been deprecated for 20 years but if you do use it, it does not take an argument so  `{\rm C}` not  `\rm{C}` although here it makes no difference as the font change stops at the $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `bookest` loads `hyperref`, which is a very bad thing to do, because it will come earlier than all the packages loaded in the document and limits the user.

It's not difficult to implement manually the features of the class. Use `book` or make a local copy of `bookest.cls`, removing the call of `hyperref` from it; better changing the name, too.